# Jenkins - Cobertura configuration

Tags: configuration, jenkins, cobertura

I'm trying to use Cobertura on my projects. I have many projects on wich there are many tests. When the job is finished, the coverage.xml file contains only the coverage info of the last component that was tested.
Here is an extract of the pom.xml file I use :

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
        <instrumentation>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/Test*.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*SubProcessAction.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*ScreenAction.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*PagingAction.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/MapAction.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*ProcessMap.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*ProcessMap$*.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*PAFAdapter.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*ProcessHandler.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*Error.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*Config.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*Dialog.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/html_internet/*.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </instrumentation>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>clean</goal>
                    <goal>cobertura</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <outputDirectory>${env.WORKSPACE}/${env.MAVEN_COBERTURA_REPORT_DIR}/</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Any ideas on my error ? Is it due to the goal "clean" ?

Thanks in advance for your answers...

Dominique

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the same `<outputDirectory>` for all your projects.  Evidently, each run will replace the previous project run and thus we end up with data for only the last project.

You may want to let cobertura use the *default* `outputDirectory` and see if that works for you.